# public vs public_html for git workflow deployment in apache?

Tags: multi-environment

I have a website setup in Craft multi-environment config for git workflow with a development branch automatically deploying via deploybot from a bitbucket repository.   I want to add an additional live server for manual deployment via deploybot, but I'm concerned about the folder structure.  I know the `public` folder in Craft is just a stand in for `web_root`, but if I allow git to deploy to the server root, won't it try to make a new `public` folder by default?

Staging setup
`/home/user/public_html/staging/public/index.php`

Live site 
`/home/user/public_html/index.php` instead of 
`/home/user/public/index.php`

I have seen where I can add a symlink to point one folder to another, but I don't think I can point `public_html` to a new public folder as I have other subdomains stored in `public_html`.   Should I just rename `public` in my Craft files to `public_html` in the local and staging files, or can I symlink `public` to `public_html` without abandoning my existing files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can make the Craft `public` folder whatever you want it to be. That allows you to deploy to any folder you like.

For example, I deploy to a `public_html` on one server, `public` on another and `web` on another server. Each of those directories are the web root of their respective site.

The only thing(s) within the `public` (or whatever you call it) directory is/are the index.php file (and whatever other js/css etc type files) you may have. As long as you can tell that file where the `craft` directory is (usually one level above the web root) - you should be golden!